# Powershell Advanced Find Replace

Tags: string, powershell

I am trying to remove part of some lines in a .txt file that all start with (Scan .....). The command I am trying is:

```
(gc A.txt).replace('(Scan*\)', '') | sc A.txt
```

Am I screwing up with the wild-card, or is powershell not able to understand that I am literally trying to find the () around Scan* and replace them as well?

Comment: If it is a regex, you need to use a regex patten, not wildcard: `\(Scan[^)]*\)` or `\(Scan.*?\)`

Comment: Try `(gc A.txt) -replace '\(Scan[^)]*\)', ''`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It's the `string.Replace` method, which is just a literal replacement.

Comment: @Joey: Yeah, that is why I suggested using `-replace`. cory1463, could you please post the sample line with the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `.replace()` method that only replaced *literal* strings, not allowing any wildcards/regular expressions. Use `-replace` in the following way:

```
(gc A.txt) -replace '\(Scan[^)]*\)', '' | sc A.txt
```

The `\(Scan[^)]*\)` regex matches:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `Scan` - a literal char sequence
- `[^)]*` - zero or more  (`*`) chars other than `)`
- `\)`  -  a literal `)`.

The replacement string is empty, since you want to remove the matches.